# SAS Enterprise Guide - process dependence and parallel execution

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am working on a project in SAS EG (7.1) which involves process dependence and parallel execution, as depicted below:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to retrieve or set relations (i.e. process_C --> program_D) between the processes programmatically? The maintenance is becoming problematic with complex projects. Ideally, I would like to be able to re-create the links between processes from external table.
2. I start the whole process with the option “Run branch from <>” process. Let’s assume that we have only 2 processors available. Is there a way to set the order of execution between process_A, B, C? The critical path of the whole flow is “begin -> process_C -> process_D -> end” hence we would like it to start with process_C in order to ensure minimum execution time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you haven't already - I would encourage you to ask on communities.sas.com also, as some of the folks there like Chris H will probably know more than anyone here; we only have a few EG users really.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, I think the answer is "no", if you mean a well defined SAS programmatic method.  At least for the relatively limited information and example you provide above, anyway.  More might be possible with metadata server - not my area of expertise.

You *can* do some of this at least using scripting via Powershell or VBScript.  EG's API is fairly wide open and not all that hard to use.  I won't suggest how as my understanding of this is limited also, but it seems like it should be possible to do what you suggest, though probably not *easy*.

---

For your second point:

First off, EG typically runs "top to bottom" if it has no other information on how to process a particular choice.  So put c->d above a/b to get it processed first.

Second, you could use conditional processing perhaps.  There should be a macro variable that tells you how many cpus you have (&SYSNCPU on my machine, hopefully same on other versions).  You could use that value to conditionally link to A then B as opposed to A+B simultaneously.  I'm not sure how easy this would be to do in a flexible fashion, though.